# Oracle Database Error | ORA-12528

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

When I try to connect to my Oracle database, I get `Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12528, TNS:listener: all appropriate instances are blocking new connections.` Also, I'm not sure if this means anything but I checked and my database is not mounted.

[image]

Comment: This is a question for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: What happens if you try to open your database? `SQL>alter database open;` then try to connect.

Comment: I would suggest, before opening the Database - to check the Alert.log and check what caused the database to unmount. If nothing suspicious - then try to open it - it should give you an error message if smth is wrong. If not - then the problem lies elsewhere and you need to give us the whole picture of the environment + the external services and applications that connect to it.

Answer (score 1):

> If the "unregister" did not complete properly, then when you go to
>   "startup" the next time, since the LISTENER did not unregister the
>   instance, you receive the error, "ORA-12528: TNS:listener: all
>   appropriate instances are blocking new connections" since an
>   "appropriate" instance is already running.

Check the status of the listener by

LSNRCTL> status

One method that should resolve this problem is to restart (bounce) the LISTENER:

LSNRCTL> stop
LSNRCTL> start

Then restart your instance: sqlplus with sysdba privileges

SQL> startup

Make sure all parameters are set.